# Wordpress API - JWT Auth - Rest_cannot_create - Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user

Tags: .htaccess, jwt, wordpress-rest-api, bearer-token

I'm using Json Web Token with Wordpress.

I succeed in generating a token “code”: “jwt_auth_valid_credential”.

But when I try to create a post to my wordpress with my token (Header : Bearer token-generated). I got a : rest_cannot_create - Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user - 401.

I have updated my HTacess In many ways. Without result. Here is the last one

```
SetEnvIf Authorization “(.*)” HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) – [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
</IfModule>
```

I’m on WPEngine.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

I got two authentifications on my website. A basic authentification and JWT Token authentification. I got a conflict between both. Its not an HTAcess problem, he is good.

Comment: Hello, how did you resolve the conflict?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't solved it. For the moment I use the classic authentication of my site